# Problem for install Anbox on Debian

Tags: debian

sorry for my English....

I to try to install **anbox** on debian Buster.

I install **anbox** on my Debian,

```
sudo apt install anbox
```

and reboot the computer

On Terminal write **man anbox**, the say that see to **/usr/share/doc/anbox/README.Debian** file, I do it.
In **/usr/share/doc/anbox/README.Debian** file say,

> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/android/binder_linux.ko and
>
> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/staging/android/ashmem_linux.ko.

I have both files, then

> You also need to download the Android image to /var/lib/anbox/android.img
>
> The pre-build image can be found at https://build.anbox.io/android-images.

I download it and bring it to **/var/lib/anbox/**

> Then start the anbox-container-manager.service and the
>   anbox-session-manager.service, anbox-session-manager.service is a systemd
>   user service.

I do it,

```
sudo systemctl start anbox-container-manager.service
systemctl --user start anbox-session-manager.service
```

> If the above commands all succeed, you can start the Android application from
>   desktop menu now. Or you launch application from command line:

```
anbox launch --package=org.anbox.appmgr --component=org.anbox.appmgr.AppViewActivity
```

I do it..

But only to come the start window,
[image]

and 20 seconds later, the window missing without Anbox to started...

Can please someone help me, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your processor do not have the features necessarily to run the Anbox.

Comment: Try install it from snap... see it in docs from anbox.io

Comment: I to tried with snap without result..

Comment: my processor  **AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core Processor**